# Make Bootstrap Tour dialogs draggable

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

SOLVED: https://jsfiddle.net/shovas/jzs1uz0d/19/ I think I was picking the wrong element to make draggable.

How do I make **Bootstrap Tour dialogs** draggable?

I would like to use **jQuery UI Draggable** with **Bootstrap Tour dialogs** but when I call `$('#dialog').draggable()` nothing seems to change.

Comment: share your html code

Comment: @ArunSharma, well, there's no html, it's just create a new Tour, which works, and using the onShown event, which fires, and then I do: $('.popover').draggable().

Comment: It would help if we could see the code from your tour.  Tour objects appear to receive their id from the JSON tour definition, so I'm curious if `#dialog` is the correct selector.  Have you tried using a selector that targets a class that tour objects share in common, like `.tour-tour` for example?  Also, it is useful to see your HTML code so that we can be sure you've included all the necessary dependencies in the `<head>`, since this all depends on jQuery, jQuery UI, Bootstrap, and Bootstrap Tour being present.

Comment: Also worth asking:  When do tour objects get added to the DOM? Do they exist at page load, or are they created dynamically when the tour is run?  If they are created dynamically, then you can only call `.draggable()` after they have been added to the DOM.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to put up some real code, I added a jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/shovas/jzs1uz0d/19/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must have been using draggable on the wrong element because I got it to work in a jsfiddle first and ported that to my real code and it worked:

https://jsfiddle.net/shovas/jzs1uz0d/19/

```
var tour = new Tour({
        element: '#step1',
        name: 'tour',
template: function ( stepIndex, step ) {
        return "" +
        "<div class='popover tour'>" +
        "       <div class='arrow'></div>" +
    " <div class='popover-header'>" +
        "   <h3 class='popover-title'></h3>" +
    " </div>" +
        " <div class='popover-content'></div>" +
        "       <div class='popover-navigation'>" +
    "         <button class='btn btn-default' data-role='prev'>« Prev</button>" +
    "         <span data-role='separator'>|</span>" +
    "         <button class='btn btn-default' data-role='next'>Next »</button>" +
    " </div>" +
        " <button class='btn btn-default' data-role='end'>End tour</button>" +
                "</div>";
},
onShown: function ( tour ) {
        console.log('onShown()')
    var curStepIndex = tour.getCurrentStep();
    var curStep = tour.getStep(curStepIndex);
    var targetElementSelector = tour._options.steps[curStepIndex].element;
    var targetElement = $(targetElementSelector).get(0);
    //$(targetElement).draggable();
    $('.popover.tour').draggable({
        handle: '.popover-header'
    });
},
steps: [
        {
                        element: '#step1',
                        title: 'Step #1',
    content: 'Lorem ipsum dolar sit amet Lorem ipsum dolar sit amet Lorem ipsum dolar sit amet Lorem ipsum dolar sit amet Lorem ipsum dolar sit amet Lorem ipsum dolar sit amet Lorem ipsum dolar sit amet.'
    }
]
});
tour.init();
tour.start();

...snip...
```